# How to Disable Auto-Loading of Un-needed Spring Beans at WebApp Start-up

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

We are using SpringBoot for our newer webapps. Our older webapps are all based on Spring MVC with most beans defined in spring config xml files. However, we would like to continue leveraging the older beans from our SpringBoot architecture.

An issue we are encountering is that at startup, SpringBoot seems to be loading all the beans in a remotely referenced spring config file, even if the new SpringBoot webapp will not be using most of those beans.

Is there a way to force Spring to only load the beans it needs at runtime? Thanks of any ideas!

Comment: What is your primary issue, is it a memory consumption?

Comment: the primary issue is some old beans that are not even needed are causing collisions with jar dependencies that are creating needless work for us to resolve.

Comment: Can you describe these "collisions" in more details? I never heard of it before.